# what is q & n in Primality Testing using Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, primality-test

Shafi Goldwasser and Joe Kilian's paper on [Primality Testing using Elliptic Curves](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Egeo2/goldwasserkilian.pdf) under the header "A PRIMALITY CRITERION USING ELLIPTIC CURVES" on page 9 contains a formula

$$\ q > n^\frac12+n^\frac14 + 1$$ and don't understand where the values of q and n are coming from.

Comment: It's indeed $ q > n ^ { \frac 1 2 } + \boldsymbol 2 n  ^ { \frac 1 2 } + 1 $. The choice of such $ q $ comes from the fact that you want to get a contradiction from these two bits in the proof: $ p \le \sqrt n $ and $ \# _ p ( A , B ) \le p + 2 \sqrt p + 1 $. On the one hand these imply $ \# _ p ( A , B ) \le n ^ { \frac 1 2 } + 2 n  ^ { \frac 1 2 } + 1 $, and on the other hand you must have $ \# _ p ( A , B ) \ge q $ (because of the part regarding the order of $ L _ p $), which can't happen if $ q $ satisfies the equation in question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Thank you for the clarification this makes much more sense now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do sincerely apologize, based on that link it would appear that this is a very poor question, should I modify it or remove it from the site?

Comment: I just thought that you could have provided more context, but there is no need to remove it.